# How to retrieve exchange rates with Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to get a simple exchange rate from USD to MXN using yahoo api but Im not getting anything back, is this just a CORS issue again or am I accessing the property incorrectly?

```
var exchangeRateURL = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20%28%22USDMXN%22%29&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys";

//Get current USD->MXN exchange rate
$.getJSON(exchangeRateURL, function(data) 
    {   
        priceInMXN = data.query.results.rate.Rate;
        document.write(priceInMXN);

    });
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What does your console say? Also that endpoint appear to provide XML, not JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass a param to return JSON (&format=json):

```
var exchangeRateURL = "http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.xchange%20where%20pair%20in%20%28%22USDMXN%22%29&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&format=json"

$.getJSON(exchangeRateURL, function(data) {
  console.log(data.query.results.rate.Rate);
});
```

Comment: I'd be more inclined to use this method - JSON is much nicer to work with. I didn't look into the API to see if this was available :-)

Comment: Most REST APIs these days either return XML or JSON, usually requiring a param for the latter, but each seems to have their own way of doing it, just need to find the param usually (format=... or type=...).  If they don't, I'd say they suck and need to add it :)
With modern day JS, its very cumbersome to interact with XML as compared to JSON.

Answer (score 3):

You're fetching XML, not JSON. Something like this will work:

```
$.get(exchangeRateURL, function(data) {
    console.log($(data).find('Rate').text());
});
```